# Parameters disappearing when report is run

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

My MySQL query has parameters in its `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
(
  ca.CodeAttribName LIKE IFNULL('{?codeattribparam','') 
  OR
  c.codetext LIKE IFNULL('{?drugnameparam}','')
)
AND (a.PCDATS BETWEEN '{?paramstartdate}' AND '{?paramenddate}')
```

When I add this code to a Crystal Report, configure the parameters and run it, the first two parameters disappear and I am only left with the date selectors.  When I fill the dates in, I get an error that tells me that not all MySQL parameters have been used.

The parameters still exist in the Command but have been removed from the parameter list in Crystal. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe that's not the solution, but there's a missing closing bracket here: `'{?codeattribparam'`

Comment: Thanks!  I hadn't noticed that.  It hasn't fixed the issue but i probably wouldn't have picked it up as I've been staring at this thing for too long

Comment: Not sure why the original post was edited.  When you dont put enough info, everyone complains.  When you put the info and context..it gets edited.  Its just subjective....

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my own issue.  Somehow the order of the parameters in the code was influential.  Changed around the order of `{?drugnameparam}` and `{?codeattribparam}` and it works.

```
WHERE
(
  c.codetext LIKE IFNULL('{?drugnameparam}','') 
  OR
  ca.CodeAttribName LIKE IFNULL('{?codeattribparam}','')
)
AND (a.PCDATS BETWEEN '{?paramstartdate}' AND '{?paramenddate}')
```